# Is there a way to continue working with the result of a method call as a Stream with Functional Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm fairly new to functional programming in Java, and I'm still experimenting with the code represented below.

I've created a method which for finding an Object within an *Array*
using stream.

Method for finding an `Account` with provided `clientIBAN`:

```
public static Account findAccountByIBAN(String clientIBAN) {

    return bankAccounts.stream()
        .filter(account -> account.getIBAN()
            .equals(clientIBAN)).findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

I want to continue working with the result returned by this method.

My idea is to modify the result in the calling method. I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do that than the one I came up with?

Method that changes the state of the `Account`:

```
public static void depositToAccount(String clientIBAN, BigDecimal depositedAmount) {
    
    findAccountByIBAN(clientIBAN)
        .setAccountBalance(findAccountByIBAN(clientIBAN)
            .getAccountBalance()
            .add(depositedAmount));
}
```

Another option I was thinking of is just to iterate over *accounts* with a stream write inside `depositToAccount()` instead of calling `findAccountByIBAN()`:

```
public static void depositToAccount(String clientIBAN, BigDecimal depositedAmount) {
    bankAccounts.stream()
        .filter(account -> account.getIBAN()
            .equals(clientIBAN)).findFirst()
        .ifPresent(balance -> 
            balance.setAccountBalance(balance.getAccountBalance().add(depositedAmount)));
}
```

The crux of my problem is that I want to keep iterating over that method with different things. I want to use `filter()` for my conditional logic instead of `if`-statements, but I cannot do that unless I can work with the result of my method as a stream.

Comment: You could make `findAccountByIBAN` return an `Optional<Account>` and continue with your `ifPresent` check in your `depositToAccount` method.

Answer (score 1):

> The crux of my problem is that I **want to keep iterating** over that method **with different things**. I want to use `filter()` for my conditional logic instead of `if`-statements, but I cannot do that unless I can work with the result of my method as a stream.

It feels like you want to extend the logic by reusing the stream?

*Stream* is a *one-time-use* mean of iteration. Once it produces the *result* or does the *final action* accordingly with its *terminal operation*, it gets **closed** and can't be used any further.

You have to place all the needed logic in the stream, there's no workaround.

But stream might produce an object with effectively encapsulates several resulting values (example from the JDK - *SummaryStatistics* classes like
[`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html)). And you can create a custom class for such a purpose.

Also, ***reminder***: `Predicate`s, `Function`s, etc. don't necessarily have to be hard-coded, you can provide them as method parameters.

---

Now, a word regarding the different versions of the code you've shared.

From the perspective of clean coding, the last version of the `depositToAccount()` isn't very great because it mixes the *responsibilities* of ***finding*** the *account* by `clientIBAN` and ***making operation*** with this *account*. It's better to keep the **separately**, like in your first version, as the [*Single responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) suggest.

And there's a couple of things which are worth to point out:

- In the first version, you're not checking whether the result returned by `findAccountByIBAN()` is not `null` which might result in a `NullPointerException`.
- As *@Eritrean* has mentioned in the comments, instead of returning `null` from `findAccountByIBAN()` if a result was not found, it would be better to change the return type to `Optional<Account>` in order to be able to leverage the Optional API.